# Python : Set the name of a Process from multiprocessing.Process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, celery, python-billiard

Is it possible to set the name of the Processes spawned by multiprocessing.Process or billiard.Process. SOmething like:

```
import billiard
for d in list:
    processes.append(billiard.Process(target=evaluate))
for p in processes:
    p.name =  'someID'
    p.start()
```

I want to find those specific processes afterwards while they are running with:

```
import psutil
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.name() == 'someID':
        print(proc)
```

Comment: `multiprocessing.Process` has a `name`-parameter you can specify.

Answer (score 1):

If I may suggest, use process id instead of process name - thats way better, and would save you a whole lot of trouble.. since you just need a reference to the process later, use their ids instead of name.

Python 3.6 [Official Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html) have illustrated a very good way of playing around with process ids. Here is a snippet from the documentation

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import os

def info(title):
    print(title)
    print('module name:', __name__)
    print('parent process:', os.getppid())
    print('process id:', os.getpid())

def f(name):
    info('function f')
    print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    info('main line')
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Also I see, `Celery` in your tags, if you're going to play with concurrent processes, I would recommend `Supervisord` instead. Gives you a very good control over the processes, if you're having a small scale project.

Comment: Thanks for the input for celery processes. I will definetly have a look on it. Because I saw that every process no matter if a subprocess with billiard.multiprocessing or a standard process has the name "celery". But also therefore it would be great to define a name for the kind of celery task. When not using celery setting the process name with process.name does not seem to work. I thought it would be great thing to name them because afterwards i can delete whole grous of processes without store their ids somewhere.